# Change unicode to image in textarea

Tags: angular, unicode

I am trying to convert unicode to image and use it in my textarea, I'm using Angular 4 and this is what I have tried.

```
my example  test
```

but after converting I get this:

```
my example <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":heart_eyes:" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.1/png/32/1f60d.png"/> test
```

How can I convert it to image wihtout using innerHTML in my textarea because it affects on other text. I want just the unicode become images and the other still text.